# В Windows Form ежесекундно выводить текстовое сообщение из файла

Tags: c#, winforms, события

В Windows Form есть textbox. Надо что бы каждую секунду текст из файла размещался в textbox. Вот код:

```
public delegate void UI();
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Объявляем событие
    public static event UI UserEvent;
    // Используем метод для запуска события
    public static void OnUserEvent()
    {
        UserEvent();
    }
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        // Добавляем обработчик события
        UserEvent += UserInfoHandler;
        while (true)
        {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
            // Запустим событие
            OnUserEvent();
        }
    }
    public void UserInfoHandler()
    {
        textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
    }
}
```

Но естественно ничего не происходит. Предполагаю что код из Form1 после InitializeComponent надо перенести куда нибудь в другое место. Но вот куда не понятно. Подскажите решение.

Comment: `ничего не происходит` - а все потому, что вы блокируете UI поток, вы попросту его ставите на паузу постоянно. Вам надо использовать потоки, либо async/await. Например можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией - `Task.Run(() => { /*Реализация*/ });`, внутри будет ваш `while`, но советую сделать полноценную Task задачу и запустить ее асинхронно. Поищите даже здесь, на RuSO информацию про async/await и думаю вы все необходимое найдете!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

Бросаем на форму `Timer`

[image: изображение таймера]

настраиваем свойства

[image: свойства таймера]

добавляем в ресурсы текстовой файл со словами, пишем код

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Text = "Пример";

        //подписываемся на собитие тика таймера
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        _buttonStart.Click += ButtonStart_Click;
        _buttonStop.Click += ButtonStop_Click;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var words = Properties.Resources.words.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
        _labelOutput.Text = words[_random.Next(0, words.Length)];
    }

    private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```